# Solution for common async pattern: Start many, await first, cancel the rest

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#

I'm looking for this pattern:

```
let startManyAwaitFirstCancelRest (n:Async<'T> list) : Async<'T> =
    // start the n asyncs,
    // return the result of the first to finish and
    // cancel the rest.
```

Comment: Perhaps start all with the same cancellation token and once the first returns a result, cancel the token source?

Comment: Or perhaps the "make the events observable, merge the observables, await them as tasks approach"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
open System
open System.Threading
open System.Threading.Tasks

let run (asyncs: list<Async<'T>>): Async<'T> =
    let cts = new CancellationTokenSource()
    let tasks = asyncs |> List.map (fun a -> Async.StartAsTask(a, cancellationToken = cts.Token))
    async {
        let! t = Async.AwaitTask ((Task.WhenAny tasks).Unwrap())
        do cts.Cancel()
        return t
    }
```

Comment: Yes, the types match and it makes sense. However, wouldn't it be better to create cts and tasks inside the async block?

Comment: does it change the idea of the solution on a conceptual level?

Comment: Not the concept, but if someone copy-pastes the code, it could cause a memory leak.